# Keras model input: 3 arrays is not the same as a tuple of 3 tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to fit my inputs to the keras model I have prepared. The input layers of my network are:

```
path_source_token_input = Input(shape=(MAX_CONTEXTS,), dtype=tf.int32)
path_input = Input(shape=(MAX_CONTEXTS,), dtype=tf.int32)
path_target_token_input = Input(shape=(MAX_CONTEXTS,), dtype=tf.int32)
```

And I specify the input this way:

```
inputs = (path_source_token_input, path_input, path_target_token_input)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=learned)  # outputs not important at this point
```

Then I load my data from a csv file, do the appropriate preprocessing and create a dataset object which looks like this in debug:
[image: dataset in debug]

Now my model compiles, all is good and then I try to fit it to the data:

```
model_x.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model_x.fit(context_paths, epochs=20, verbose=2)
```

But it throws this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), for inputs ['input_1', 'input_2', 'input_3'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: []...

At this point I am not sure what is wrong, because in debug it seems that my dataset is a tuple of length 3 (the way I want it and specify as 'input') but something goes wrong. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You built the model to get three different inputs: `(path_source_token_input, path_input, path_target_token_input)`.

You need data that is a list of 3 arrays. One array for `path_source_token_input`, another array for `path_input`, and a third array for `path_target_token_input`.

`context_paths = [array1, array2, array3]`.

Where:

```
array1.shape == (anything, MAX_CONTEXTS)
array2.shape == (anything, MAX_CONTEXTS)   
array3.shape == (anything, MAX_CONTEXTS)
```

Don't think that the outputs are not important, you cannot fit without outputs if you didn't prepare a model with a special loss for this.

---

### Data process

Just create the arrays, don't use a dataset:

```
def loadFile(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
                

    triplets = [l.split(" ") for l in lines]  #(16000, 430)
    singles = [[t.split(',') for t in line] for line in triplets]  #(16000, 430, 3)

    data = np.array(singles).astype(np.int32)
    data_source = data[:,:,0]
    data_path = data[:,:,1]
    data_target = data[:,:,2]    

    return [data_source, data_path, data_target]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am currently trying to do so but I have trouble splitting my `ParallelMapDataset` object into three arrays. it is a result of dataset.map function, is it possible to do so in the map function or is there a handy tf function for this. I have been unsuccessful in searching the tf.data.experimental.csvdataset documentation. Thanks

Comment: What is the original data? Is there a special reason to use a tensorflow dataset?

Comment: The original data is a csv file where a single line is a set of 430 triplets of integers in the form of int_1,int_2,int_3 where these triplets are separated by a whitespace character. I have tried to construct a tf preprocess pipeline so I used the tf dataset.

Comment: The file has only one line? Is `MAX_CONTEXTS = 430`?

Comment: Could you post the beginning one of these lines? A few triplets is ok.

Comment: Sorry the file has about 16000 lines, an example `780790805,-1874004963,406953878 780790805,-1874004870,1678368888 780790805,-1874004808,473499926 780790805,-1874004746,892314868` and yes, MAX_CONTEXTS is 430.

Comment: This doesn't do what I want, it takes too much time to process the file and the resulting `singles` are single characters, e.g. `[['"'], ['1'], ['4'], ['9'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['2'], ['5'], ['4'], ['', ''], ['8'], ['9'], ...]`. I will try on my own, thank you.